# How to provide hidden line breaks for error fields in HTML forms?

Tags: html, hidden, line-breaks

> I need to provide one line gap between the error field and the input box, but if  I do it in the manner below, even when the errorfield is not shown, there is extra space between two input fields. Is there any way to hide the line breaks? or anything at all to avoid this problem, as the look and feel of the page is getting spoiled..

```
<div class="fileds-inner"
                            style="${dealerVO.pageConfig.dealerName.visibility}">
                            <div class="field-left">
                                <label><spring:message
                                        code="rmp.dealer.label.dealer_name" /><sup class="error-msg">${dealerVO.pageConfig.dealerName.mandatory}</sup>
                                    :</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-right">
                                <form:input path="dealerName" />
                                <br></br><form:errors path="dealerName" cssClass="error-field" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide details of what server-side language you're using here

Comment: you're going to have to post this somewhere we can see your CSS. I have absolutely no idea what it looks like or is supposed to look like from this code block :(.